# PHP: How to delete all array elements after an index

Tags: php, arrays, function, output, associative-array

Is it possible to delete all array elements after an index?

```
$myArrayInit = array(1=>red, 30=>orange, 25=>velvet, 45=>pink);
```

now some "magic"

```
$myArray = delIndex(30, $myArrayInit);
```

to get

```
$myArray = array(1=>red, 30=>orange);
```

due to the keys in `$myArray` are not successive, I don't see a chance for `array_slice()`

**`Please note`** : **Keys have to be preserved! + I do only know the Offset Key!!**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Without making use of loops.

```
<?php
    $myArrayInit = [1 => 'red', 30 => 'orange', 25 => 'velvet', 45 => 'pink']; //<-- Your actual array
    $offsetKey = 25; //<--- The offset you need to grab

    //Lets do the code....
    $n = array_keys($myArrayInit); //<---- Grab all the keys of your actual array and put in another array
    $count = array_search($offsetKey, $n); //<--- Returns the position of the offset from this array using search
    $new_arr = array_slice($myArrayInit, 0, $count + 1, true);//<--- Slice it with the 0 index as start and position+1 as the length parameter.
    print_r($new_arr);
```

**`Output :`**

```
Array
(
    [1] => red
    [30] => orange
    [25] => velvet
)
```

Comment: I think your answer is more good coz it preserve the key association :)

Comment: Thanks sankar to let me notice the 4th arg of array_slice :)

Comment: guys, you are so phantastic!!! Thank you VERY VARY VERY VERY MUCH!!!

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$arr = array(1=>red, 30=>orange, 25=>velvet, 45=>pink);
$pos = array_search('30', array_keys($arr));
$arr= array_slice($arr,0,$pos+1,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

See [demo](https://eval.in/102710)

Comment: **But the keys are not preserved.**

Comment: If the OP doesn't care about it, then yours is the best :)

Comment: that does delete the prev elements, not the following

Comment: Ooops.. I will update my answer

Comment: @viktor have updated my answer. But Sankar deserves the correct answer

Comment: @Nouphal.M, If you replace `$pos` with `$pos+1` you will get the correct result... currently it shows just the `red` skipping `orange`.

Comment: My **+1** mate. Welcome to 4K club :)

Comment: Code only answers are low value on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I'd iterate over the array up until you reach the key you want to truncate the array thereafter, and add those items to a new - temporary array, then set the existing array to null, then assign the temp array to the existing array.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a flag value to determine your limit:

```
$myArrayInit = array(1=>'red', 30=>'orange', 25=>'velvet', 45=>'pink');

$new_array = delIndex(30,$myArrayInit);

function delIndex($limit,$array){

    $limit_reached=false;

    foreach($array as $ind=>$val){

        if($limit_reached==true){
            unset($array[$ind]);
        }
        if($ind==$limit){
            $limit_reached=true;
        }

    }
    return $array;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: **+1** The above code also preserves the key-association and also no `array functions` were used !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function delIndex($afterIndex, $array){
    $flag = false;
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        if($flag == true)
            unset($array[$key]);
        if($key == $afterIndex)
             $flag = true; 
    }
    return $array;
}
```

This code is not tested

Comment: Code only answers are low value on SO.