# PHP - fast way to get previous array elements before specific key

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get all previous element before a specific array key.

Here is my array:

```
$key = 256;

$array = (
125 => array(571, 570), 
284 => array(567, 566),
256 => array(562, 560),
110 => array(565, 563),
);
```

Now I want result like this:

```
$array = (
125 => array(571, 570), 
284 => array(567, 566)
);
```

Comment: possible duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713639/how-to-get-next-key-in-an-array-from-given-key-in-php

Comment: Please read again. It doesn't solve my problem..

Comment: @MDAbubakar Please rephrase your question, do you mean the elements *before* a given key? Because that's the results you are wanting.

Comment: Yes... I want to get elements before given key

Comment: This is sure to be a duplicate.  I'll have a quick look.

Comment: Where is the attempt to self-solve?  It didn't make its way into the posted question.

Comment: Is `$key` guaranteed to exist in the array?  This is a necessary question for any method using `array_search ()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to delete all array elements after an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851127/php-how-to-delete-all-array-elements-after-an-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through and push values to a `newArray` until you hit the key you are searching for:

```
$Key = 256;

$array = array(
"125" => array(571, 570), 
"284" => array(567, 566),
"256" => array(562, 560),
"110" => array(565, 563),
);

$newArray = [];

foreach($array as $key => $value) 
{   
  if($key == $Key) break;
  $newArray[$key] = $value;
}

print_r ($newArray); 
/*
=> Array ( 
    [125] => Array ( [0] => 571 [1] => 570 ) 
    [284] => Array ( [0] => 567 [1] => 566 ) 
   )
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the numeric index of key first using [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). Then slice the array from the beginning to key's index using [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$index = array_search($key, array_keys($array)); // Get the numeric index of search key
$result = array_slice($array, 0, $index, true);  // Slice from 0 up to index

print_r($result); // Print result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this weird thing:

```
$key = 256;

$array = array(
    125 => array(571, 570), 
    284 => array(567, 566),
    256 => array(562, 560),
    110 => array(565, 563),
);

print_r(array_slice($array, array_search($key, array_keys($array)), null, true));
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [256] => Array
        (
            [0] => 562
            [1] => 560
        )

    [110] => Array
        (
            [0] => 565
            [1] => 563
        )

)
```

**UPDATE**

I realize now that I look again, I did it backwards.  I call `dyslexic` moment...   To do it the right way is like this

```
print_r(array_slice($array, 0, array_search($key, array_keys($array)),true));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$position = array_search($key, array_keys($array));
$output = array_slice($array, 0, $position);
print_r($output);
```

DEMO: https://3v4l.org/nmnDv