# How to get next value from match value in foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How to get next value from match value in loop? I need '1010-1040' key in array.

```
<?php

$arr = Array
(
    '0900-0930' => 0,
    '0935-1005' => 0,
    '1010-1040' => 0,
    '1045-1115' => 0
);


$matchVal = '0935-1005';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    
    if($matchVal == $key){
        echo $key.'<br />';
    }
    echo next($arr); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Related: [PHP - fast way to get previous array elements before specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47503007/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$arr = Array
(
    '0900-0930' => 0,
    '0935-1005' => 0,
    '1010-1040' => 0,
    '1045-1115' => 0
);


$matchVal = '0935-1005';

$keys = array_keys($arr);
print $keys[array_search($matchVal,$keys)+1];
```

**Output**

```
1010-1040
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      <?php 
        $arr = Array
        (
            '0900-0930' => 0,
            '0935-1005' => 0,
            '1010-1040' => 0,
            '1045-1115' => 0
        );
        $keys = array_keys($arr);
        $matchVal = '0935-1005';
        $matched = array_search($matchVal, $keys); // $key = 1;
        $nextindex = $matched + 1;
        $nextValue = $arr[$nextindex];
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
<?php

$arr = Array
(
    '0900-0930' => 0,
    '0935-1005' => 0,
    '1010-1040' => 0,
    '1045-1115' => 0
);


$matchVal = '0935-1005';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    if($matchVal == $key){
        echo $key.'<br />';
    }
    next($arr);
    echo key($arr)."<br/>;
}
?>
```